# Select subquery produces result but not if used within an update clause

Tags: mysql, sql

This code produces this result

```
 SELECT PER.GLACCOUNT, PER.PERIOD,(SELECT GL.[CLOSING_CREDIT] 
    FROM [EMBDATA].[DBO].[_EMB_GL_ACTUALVALUESTYP] AS GL
    WHERE GL.PERIOD = (DBO.GETMAXPERIOD(PER.GLACCOUNT,PER.PERIOD)) 
    AND GL.ID COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS   =            
   COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS ) AS BALANCE
   FROM [DBO].[GL_PERIOD_BAL] AS PER
   WHERE LEFT(PER.GLACCOUNT,4) = 'NM01' AND [BAL.TYPE] = 'R'
   ORDER BY PER.GLACCOUNT,PER.PERIOD    GLACCOUNT   PERIOD  BALANCE)
```

Result

```
NM01-4100-0015  2015-12 7081557.0000
NM01-4100-0016  2015-12 0.0000
NM01-4100-0017  2015-12 0.0000
NM01-4100-0018  2015-12 12329577.0000
NM01-4100-0019  2015-12 1622830124.0000
NM01-4100-0020  2015-12 0.0000
NM01-4100-0021  2015-12 23747.0000
NM01-4100-0022  2015-12 0.0000
NM01-4100-0023  2015-12 1623014.0000
```

But if I want to combine it into a update statement, it isn't updating
the code.

```
UPDATE [DBO].[GL_PERIOD_BAL]  
SET [CLOSING_CREDIT] = (SELECT GL.[CLOSING_CREDIT] 
FROM [EMBRACEDATA].[DBO].[_EMB_GL_ACTUALVALUESTYP] GL
WHERE GL.PERIOD = (DBO.GETMAXPERIOD(GLACCOUNT,PERIOD))
AND GL.ID COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS  =
GLACCOUNT  COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS)
WHERE LEFT(GLACCOUNT,4) = 'NM01' AND [BAL.TYPE] = 'R'
```

Answer (score 0):

When you try updating using subquery in oracle, if the subquery returns more than one row, it gives the following error message :
 "single-row subquery returns more than one row"

I guess this is the case with you too. A subquery should not return more than one row, for successful update.
You would need to use one of the various clauses that help to limit the number of rows fetched to one, which may be the top clause, limit clause etc. This should be decided/manipulated based on what data you want to be selected for the update.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your input.

I have managed to find the solution by adding an alias to all columns.

```
UPDATE [dbo].[GL_PERIOD_BAL]  

       SET[dbo].[GL_PERIOD_BAL] . [CLOSING_CREDIT] = (SELECT GL.   [CLOSING_CREDIT] 
                      FROM [EmbraceData].[dbo].[_EMB_GL_ACTUALVALUESTYP]   AS GL
      WHERE GL.PERIOD = (DBO.gETMAXPERIOD([dbo].  [GL_PERIOD_BAL].GLACCOUNT,[dbo].  [GL_PERIOD_BAL].PERIOD)) 
                          AND GL.ID COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
                         = [dbo].[GL_PERIOD_BAL].GLACCOUNT      
        COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS)
                         WHERE LEFT([dbo].[GL_PERIOD_BAL].GLACCOUNT,4) = 'NM01'   AND    [dbo].[GL_PERIOD_BAL].[BAL.TYPE] = 'R'
```